# Link posting on Facebook wall without permission

Tags: facebook, permissions, share

So if I click this link http://cool.factsclub.site/?p=604 you see the "google captha" its basically fake and set so that if you press 3 it will share the link automatically to FB. How the can they share it without asking me first if I want to share it. Normally it would open a Status Update box.

I am just curios if you know how the trick works.

Thanks in advance!